# enviar mi variable GET a mi base de datos SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

trato de enviar una variable que estoy obteniendo por el método GET pero quiero almacenar esta variable en mi base de datos estoy usando lo siguiente:

```
$nombre = $_GET['variable'] ;
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$notas = $_POST['notas'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sanciones");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$ejecucion ="INSERT INTO `sanciones` ( `nombre_personal`, `tipo_sancion`, `notas`) VALUES ('$nombre', '$tipo', '$notas')";
```

me podrían indicar que estoy haciendo mal ya que todo se envía excepto la variable $nombre ese campo queda vacío dentro de la base de datos

Comment: Muy raro que envíes get y post al mismo tiempo... Puedes mostrar cómo es el formulario en el que lo envías?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa en tu formulario html como se llama la variable nombre.
En el codigo php le has dejado 'variable', pero posiblemente sea asi
`$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];`